# Configuring public key of users via gitolite throws error

Tags: git, gitolite

I have added the public key of a user and pushed to the server.
But while running the `gl-setup` I have used like `/tmp/id_rsa.pub` instead of `/tmp/rekha.pub`.

Now I have altered the file name and then again tried to run the `gl-setup`.

It shows the message at last like this

```
rekha.pub maps to user id_rsa, not rekha.
You will not be able to access gitolite with this key.
Look for the 'ssh troubleshooting' link in http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/.
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `gl-setup` is a [gitolite V2 or 'g2' command](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/g2/src/gl-setup).
The [current documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/qi.html) for installation is for [GitoliteV3 (or 'g3')](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html): an upgrade would be wise (for ease of support)

Looking at the [sources of gitolite](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=repo%3Asitaramc%2Fgitolite+%22maps+to%22&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=), I find [`sshkeys-lint`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/g2/src/sshkeys-lint) which will check for gitolite admin user:

```perl
if ($admin) {
    my $fp = fprint("$admin.pub");
    my $fpu = ( $seen_fprints{$fp}{user} || 'no access' );
    # dbg("fpu = $fpu, admin=$admin");
    die "\t\t*** FATAL ***\n" .
        "$admin.pub maps to $fpu, not $admin.\n" .
        "You will not be able to access gitolite with this key.\n" .
        "Look for the 'ssh troubleshooting' link in http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/.\n"
    if $fpu ne "user $admin";
}
```

You might need to try again `gl-setup rekha.pub`, as explained by the [ssh troubleshooting for g2](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/d59bc351f8a037b0adf16cc52fe34170665e4f81/doc/ssh-troubleshooting.mkd#typical-causes).
If that fails, check your ~gitolite-user-account/.ssh/authorized-keys and make sure `id_rsa` is replaced, if present, by `rekha`.

---

The [OP thillaiselvan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284113/thillaiselvan) reports in the comment having a working Gitolite again:

> I have achieved it by:
>
> - replacing deleting the `id_rsa` content in the authorized-keys file.
> - Created a fresh pub key for the `rekha` user.
> - And then freshly pushed it which is a huge work around.
>
> Now it works fine :)

Comment: I have achieved it by replacing deleting the id_rsa content in the authorized-keys file. Created a fresh pub key for the rekha user. And then freshly pushed it which is a huge work around. Now it works fine :)

Comment: @thillaiselvan Excellent. At least it works again. I have included your feedback in the answer for more visibility.